# Find the rule of $f(x)$ given the following definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined for $x>2$, where $a>1$ and $b>1$, such that:
$$\int_{3}^{ab+2}{f\left( x \right)dx=\int_{3}^{a+2}{f\left( x \right)dx+\int_{3}^{b+2}{f\left( x \right)dx}}}$$

Find $f(x)$.

---

In the actual question, there were a couple of functions to choose from, but I don't think integrating each one is a good approach. I didn't know how to find $f(x)$ with just the given, any ideas?

---

EDIT: Attempt (not sure if the third step is correct):

$$F\left( ab+2 \right)-F\left( 3 \right)=F\left( a+2 \right)-F\left( 3 \right)+F\left( b+2 \right)-F\left( 3 \right)$$
$$F\left( ab+2 \right)=F\left( a+2 \right)+F\left( b+2 \right)-F\left( 3 \right)$$
$$F\left( ab \right)=F\left( a \right)+F\left( b \right)-F\left( 1 \right)$$

It looks logarithmic: $F(x)=\log _{e}\left( x \right)$ which satisfies $F\left( ab \right)=F\left( a \right)+F\left( b \right)-F\left( 1 \right)$
so $f(x)=\log _{e}\left( x \right)$.

But this doesn't satisfy the integral equation above so I changed it:

$$f\left( x \right)=\frac{1}{x-2}$$

which is included in the provided answers

Comment: Assume that you've integrated the arbitrary  function to obtain $F(x)$, evaluate the definite integral, and see which functions would satisfy the above equation.

Comment: ill edit in my attempt, not sure it's correct tho

Comment: not $f(x)=\ln x$ but $F(x-2)=\ln x$ and so $f(x)={1\over x-2}$ as in your answers

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky if $F\left( x-2 \right)=\ln \left( x \right)$ then $F\left( x \right)=\ln \left( x+2 \right)$ and so $f\left( x \right)=\frac{1}{x+2}$, am i right ? I think it might be $F\left( x+2 \right)=\ln \left( x \right)$ ? since i did $-2$ in step three, i should do $+2$ in the end. i think

Comment: yes, you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.

From
$F( ab )=F( a )+F( b )-F( 1 )
$,
we can fiddle a bit
to get
$F( ab )-F(1)=F( a )-F(1)+F( b )-F( 1 )
$.
Therefore,
if
$g(x) = F(x)-F(1)$,
$g(ab) = g(a)+g(b)
$.

*This* is the log functional equation,
so
$g(x)
=\log_b(x)
=\ln(x)/\ln(b)
$
for some base $b$.

Therefore,
$F(x)
=g(x)+F(1)
=\log_b(x)+F(1)
$.

Comment: okay so $F\left( ab \right)-1=g\left( ab \right)$ and $F\left( a \right)-1=g\left( a \right)$ but I don't understand how $F\left( b \right)-F\left( 1 \right)=g\left( b \right)$

Comment: That is how g(x) is defined.

Comment: it's defined as $g\left( x \right)=F\left( x \right)-1$ so that $g\left( b \right)=F\left( b \right)-1$, but $g\left( b \right)≠F\left( b \right)-F\left( 1 \right)$ unless $F\left( 1 \right)=1$ ? i feel like im missing something

Comment: You are right. My mistake. I should have defined g(x) = F(x)-F(1). I have changed my answer.

Comment: Oh i get it, i made the mistake of simplifying in step 2, i should've just done: $$g\left( x \right)=F\left( x+2 \right)-F\left( 3 \right)$$ $$g\left( ab \right)=g\left( a \right)+g\left( b \right)$$ $$g\left( x \right)=\log \left( x \right)$$ $$F\left( x+2 \right)-F\left( 3 \right)=\log \left( x \right)$$ $$F\left( x \right)-F\left( 1 \right)=\log \left( x-2 \right)$$ $$f\left( x \right)=\frac{1}{x-2}$$

Comment: Also, you don't need \left( and \right) in this case. Those are used when the expression is tall, like with a \frac.